# how to change min date of kendo date picker: Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker, mindate

I am creating a web app in which I have 2 date time textbox(txtFromDate, txtToDate), for which I am using Kendo-UI,

On my page load I am setting min date for my `txtToDate`

Which looks like below

```
$('#txtToDate').data("kendoDatePicker").min(new Date($('#txtFromDate').val()));
```

the above code works properly and setting the min date for `txtToDate` textbox properly,

but the problem is

> when user changes from date let say from (05/08/2019) to (05/20/2019)

the min date for `txtToDate` should be changed `from 05/08/2019 to 05/20/2019`

but nothing happens, below is my onchange function

```
$('#txtFromDate').change(function () {
    $('#txtToDate').data("kendoDatePicker").min(new Date($('#txtFromDate').val()));
});
```

how can I reset the min date for txtToDate Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're binding to the change event of the input, instead of the kendo widget.

Replace

```
$('#txtFromDate').change(function () {
```

with

```
$('#txtFromDate').data("kendoDatePicker").bind("change", function () {
```

Edited to add: you may also prefer to just use Kendo's [date range picker](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/daterangepicker/overview)

Comment: But the problem is with `$('txtToDate')` and not with `$('txtFromDate')`

Comment: Can you post a dojo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @GaloisGirl do you know how can I refer to datepicker on the OnChange event of a dropdown inside Kendo Grid? I posted a similar question recently and didn't find any answers.